# Jquery: contextMenu reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

Hi I enconter some problem with: 
http://jsfiddle.net/fNgXX/4/

What I want: When user doubleclick on word, depending on text, I ll show different contextMenu.
1st bug here:

```
$('word').click( function(e) {
```

I had to use .click to for make it work for double click. I have no idea why. when I put dblclick I have to click 4 time to show contextMenu.

2nd problem (more important): When you double click on:

```
<word>test</word>
```

You see the contextMenu with Edit. But after that when you click on notest it suppose to show a contextMenu Cut but it didn't, he still show the previous contextMenu.

So My question is how to reset the conextMenu?

Answer (score 1):

You had 2 issues, first you were calling the function to create the `contextMenu` **before** actually creating it that's why initially you had to click it more times (if you arrange it correctly `.dblclick()` works as expected). Also the other issue you had is that you were not really overriding the `items` option of the `contextMenu`, and since the `contextMenu` already existed, all future calls to `word.contextMenu()` where just showing it, but not overriding the existing one, I've changed your `changeWord` function to:

```
changeWord = function(word){
    var item={};
    if (word.text() == 'test') {
        item['edit']={name: "Edit", icon: "edit"};
    } else {
        item['cut']= {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"} 
    }
    console.log(item);
    $.contextMenu( 'destroy', 'word' );
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: 'word',
        trigger: 'none',
        items: item
    }); 
    word.contextMenu();
}
```

And it works as expected, you can see it on **[this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/csBjg/)**...

Comment: OK. Thank you very much for you help and you good explaination.

Comment: I hope it helps you, and if it does it'd be cool if you could accept and upvote my answer...

Comment: I did it. I can t before that because not enought reputation. Again thank you very much.